# Extract parts of current working directory as variable

Tags: bash

I googled for several hours and could not find a solution for the following issue (at least I did not find one I could understand and adapt).

My cwd is:

```
/home/ubuntu/data/modelling/Iamvariable/Var1/PRODUCTION/ANALYSIS/Var2/DIHEDRALS
```

and I need to extrakt the "text" behind `Var1` and `Var2`.

I would like to scan the pwd output from right to left since the file path starting could change but the path starting after `Iamvaribale` will stay always the same. By means of number of elements in path and except `Iamvaribale` (and of course `Var1` and `Var2`) also the folder names will stay the same.

How can I achieve this in a bash sricpt?

```
Var1 = 
Var2 =
```

edit:

```
/home/ubuntu/data/modelling/Iamvariable/Var1/PRODUCTION/ANALYSIS/Var2/DIHEDRALS
```

basically everything in capital letters is fixed. If there is no easy solution where

```
/home/ubuntu/data/modelling
```

is not fixed this is OK to be set as fixed. But it would be better to have it not fixed, to have it more flexible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parameter expansion:

```
#!/bin/bash
path=/home/ubuntu/data/modelling/Iamvariable/Var1/PRODUCTION/ANALYSIS/Var2/DIHEDRALS
var1=${path%/PRODUCTION/ANALYSIS/*}
var1=${var1##*/}
echo "$var1"

var2=${path#*/PRODUCTION/ANALYSIS/}
var2=${var2%/*}
echo "$var2"
```

`#` removes from the beginning, `%` from the end of the parameter. Doubling the character means the largest possible string will be removed.

Comment: Could you explain further how does `var1=${var1%%/*}` work? Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! For Var 2 I understand that this will work out but for Var1 I don't. How can search for something whitch is variable. Maybe I translated wrong. With that expression I meant that on this position the folder could be namend as anything.

Comment: In theory we could read out what is after modelling and put this temporary var as search for var1. However I would like to have it, if possible, more robust since every thing before "Iamvarible" could be changed

Comment: Can you give some examples? What parts of the path are fixed?

Comment: I added examples above.

Comment: another idea could be to use   cd ../.. to go to the position of interrest and perform the parameter expansion as mentioned above. It looks a bit messy then. However if there is a better solution for that, this would be good.

Comment: @DavidSchroeder: Check the update.

Comment: I just noticed, it workes perfect thanks